# Where's the development package's documents?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Recently I want to do some development tasks for MySQL.
I'm in Ubuntu 14.04, and I install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package already.

I know I can google some tutorials to learn how to use it.
But I wondered that is there any official documentation attacked in the package itself? If it is, where and how can I find it?

Comment: Well, it'll presumably be in the usual place, some subfolder of `/usr/share/doc`. If not, have you tried searching for a corresponding `-doc` package?

Comment: @underscore_d: There is no `-doc` package, but I do found an example in `/usr/share/doc`, just one example code, but that is about the *user definable function* that doesn't fit my need.